# validated cloudformation yaml template

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template which when I validate it it appears it appears to be valid I get no errors using the linter tool in Atom and I have also use an online yaml validate tool which confirms it is correct but when I go to deploy the template in CFN it fails with error

```
Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AgentserviceSNSTopic] in the Resources block of the template
```

I can't see any errors (am not sure how the formatting will be but the template is below )

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AgentService Web infra
Outputs:
  AgentServiceFQDN:
    Value:
      'Fn::GetAtt':
        - AgentServiceELB
        - DNSName
Parameters:
  AZ:
    Default: 'ap-southeast-2a, ap-southeast-2b'
    Description: >-
      Comma delimited list of AvailabilityZones where the instances will be
      created
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  InstanceProfile:
    Default: >-
      arn:aws:iam::112888586165:instance-profile/AdvanceCodeDeployInstanceProfile
    Description: >-
      Use the full ARN for SimpleCodeDeployInstanceProfile or
      AdvancedCodeDeployInstanceProfile
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    ConstraintDescription: 'Must be a valid EC2 instance type, such as t2.medium'
    Default: t2.medium
    Description: Provide InstanceType to be used
    Type: String
  KeyName:
    ConstraintDescription: The name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
    Default: LMBRtraining
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
  PublicSubnets:
    Default: 'subnet-bb0a3ade,subnet-fedd8389'
    Description: Comma delimited list of public subnets
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  VPCID:
    Default: vpc-a18eccc4
    Description: VPC ID
    Type: String
  WindowsAMIID:
    Default: ami-5a989d39
    Description: Windows AMI ID with IIS
    Type: String
  myIP:
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    Description: 'Enter your IP address in CIDR notation, e.g. 100.150.200.225/32'
    Type: String
Resources:
  AgentServiceASG:
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        Ref: AZ
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: '600'
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: AgentServiceLaunchConfig
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - Ref: AgentServiceELB
      MaxSize: '2'
      MinSize: '2'
      NotificationConfiguration:
        NotificationTypes:
          - 'autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH'
          - 'autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR'
          - 'autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE'
          - 'autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR'
      TopicARN:
          Ref: AgentServiceSNSTopic
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: 'true'
          Value: AgentServiceServer
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        Ref: PublicSubnets
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
  AgentServiceAutoscaleDownPolicy:
    Properties:
      AdjustmentType: ChangeInCapacity
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: AgentServiceASG
      Cooldown: '300'
      ScalingAdjustment: '-1'
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
  AgentServiceAutoscaleUpPolicy:
    Properties:
      AdjustmentType: ChangeInCapacity
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: AgentServiceASG
      Cooldown: '300'
      ScalingAdjustment: '1'
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
  AgentServiceCloudWatchCPUAlarmHigh:
    Properties:
      AlarmActions:
        - Ref: AgentServiceAutoscaleUpPolicy
        - Ref: AgentServiceSNSTopic
      AlarmDescription: SNS Notification and scale up if CPU Util is Higher than 90% for 10 mins
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Name: AutoScalingGroupName
          Value:
            Ref: AgentServiceASG
      EvaluationPeriods: '2'
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/EC2
      Period: '300'
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: '90'
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  AgentServiceCloudWatchCPUAlarmLow:
    Properties:
      AlarmActions:
        - Ref: AgentServiceAutoscaleDownPolicy
        - Ref: AgentserviceSNSTopic
      AlarmDescription: SNS Notification and scale down if CPU Util is less than 70% for 10 mins
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Name: AutoScalingGroupName
          Value:
            Ref: AgentServiceASG
      EvaluationPeriods: '2'
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/EC2
      Period: '300'
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: '70'
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  AgentServiceELB:
    Properties:
      ConnectionDrainingPolicy:
        Enabled: 'true'
        Timeout: '60'
      CrossZone: true
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        Interval: '15'
        Target: 'HTTP:80/index.html'
        Timeout: '5'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '3'
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: '80'
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      LoadBalancerName: AgentServiceELB
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        Ref: PublicSubnets
      Tags:
        - Key: Network
          Value: public
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
  AgentServiceLaunchConfig:
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: InstanceProfile
      ImageId:
        Ref: WindowsAMIID
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64':
          'Fn::Join':
            - ''
            - - |
                <script>
              - |
                echo hello world > c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.html
              - |
                hostname >> c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.html
              - "if not exist \\"c:\\temp\\" mkdir c:\\temp\\n"
              - >
                powershell.exe -Command Read-S3Object -BucketName
                aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest -Key codedeploy-agent.msi -File
                c:\\temp\\codedeploy-agent.msi
              - >
                c:\\temp\\codedeploy-agent.msi /quiet /l
                c:\\temp\\host-agent-install-log.txt
              - |
                powershell.exe -Command Get-Service -Name codedeployagent
              - |
                </script>
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
  AgentServiceSNSTopic:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
  AgentServiceSecurityGroup:
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
      InstanceAccessHTTPS:
        Properties:
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '443'
          GroupId: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '443'
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
      InstanceAccessPSremote:
        Properties:
          CidrIp: 198.18.0.0/24
          FromPort: '5985'
          GroupId: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '5985'
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
      InstanceAccessRDP:
        Properties:
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '3389'
          GroupId: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '3389'
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
      InstanceAccessSMB:
        Properties:
          CidrIp: 198.18.0.0/24
          FromPort: '445'
          GroupId: AgentServiceSecurityGroup
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '445'
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPCID
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
```

Comment: This line is a syntax error: `- "if not exist \\"c:\\temp\\" mkdir c:\\temp\\n"`  It should probably be `- "if not exist \"c:\\temp\" mkdir c:\\temp\\n"`

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting to know which online validator accepted your "valid YAML".

The [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=AWSTemplateFormatVersion%3A%20%272010-09-09%27%0ADescription%3A%20AgentService%20Web%20infra%0AOutputs%3A%0A%20%20AgentServiceFQDN%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Value%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Fn%3A%3AGetAtt%27%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20AgentServiceELB%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20DNSName%0AParameters%3A%0A%20%20AZ%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20%27ap-southeast-2a%2C%20ap-southeast-2b%27%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20%3E-%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Comma%20delimited%20list%20of%20AvailabilityZones%20where%20the%20instances%20will%20be%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20created%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20CommaDelimitedList%0A%20%20InstanceProfile%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20%3E-%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A112888586165%3Ainstance-profile%2FAdvanceCodeDeployInstanceProfile%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20%3E-%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Use%20the%20full%20ARN%20for%20SimpleCodeDeployInstanceProfile%20or%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AdvancedCodeDeployInstanceProfile%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20String%0A%20%20InstanceType%3A%0A%20%20%20%20ConstraintDescription%3A%20%27Must%20be%20a%20valid%20EC2%20instance%20type%2C%20such%20as%20t2.medium%27%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20t2.medium%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20Provide%20InstanceType%20to%20be%20used%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20String%0A%20%20KeyName%3A%0A%20%20%20%20ConstraintDescription%3A%20The%20name%20of%20an%20existing%20EC2%20KeyPair.%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20LMBRtraining%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20Name%20of%20an%20existing%20EC2%20KeyPair%20to%20enable%20SSH%20access%20to%20the%20instances%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3AKeyPair%3A%3AKeyName%27%0A%20%20PublicSubnets%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20%27subnet-bb0a3ade%2Csubnet-fedd8389%27%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20Comma%20delimited%20list%20of%20public%20subnets%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20CommaDelimitedList%0A%20%20VPCID%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20vpc-a18eccc4%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20VPC%20ID%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20String%0A%20%20WindowsAMIID%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%20ami-5a989d39%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20Windows%20AMI%20ID%20with%20IIS%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20String%0A%20%20myIP%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Default%3A%200.0.0.0%2F0%0A%20%20%20%20Description%3A%20%27Enter%20your%20IP%20address%20in%20CIDR%20notation%2C%20e.g.%20100.150.200.225%2F32%27%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20String%0AResources%3A%0A%20%20AgentServiceASG%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AvailabilityZones%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AZ%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20DesiredCapacity%3A%20%272%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20HealthCheckGracePeriod%3A%20%27600%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20HealthCheckType%3A%20ELB%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LaunchConfigurationName%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceLaunchConfig%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LoadBalancerNames%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceELB%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20MaxSize%3A%20%272%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20MinSize%3A%20%272%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20NotificationConfiguration%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NotificationTypes%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27autoscaling%3AEC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27autoscaling%3AEC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27autoscaling%3AEC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27autoscaling%3AEC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20TopicARN%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceSNSTopic%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Tags%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Key%3A%20Name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PropagateAtLaunch%3A%20%27true%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Value%3A%20AgentServiceServer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20VPCZoneIdentifier%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20PublicSubnets%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AAutoScaling%3A%3AAutoScalingGroup%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceAutoscaleDownPolicy%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AdjustmentType%3A%20ChangeInCapacity%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AutoScalingGroupName%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceASG%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Cooldown%3A%20%27300%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ScalingAdjustment%3A%20%27-1%27%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AAutoScaling%3A%3AScalingPolicy%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceAutoscaleUpPolicy%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AdjustmentType%3A%20ChangeInCapacity%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AutoScalingGroupName%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceASG%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Cooldown%3A%20%27300%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ScalingAdjustment%3A%20%271%27%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AAutoScaling%3A%3AScalingPolicy%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceCloudWatchCPUAlarmHigh%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AlarmActions%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceAutoscaleUpPolicy%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceSNSTopic%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AlarmDescription%3A%20SNS%20Notification%20and%20scale%20up%20if%20CPU%20Util%20is%20Higher%20than%2090%25%20for%2010%20mins%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ComparisonOperator%3A%20GreaterThanThreshold%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Dimensions%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Name%3A%20AutoScalingGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Value%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceASG%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EvaluationPeriods%3A%20%272%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20MetricName%3A%20CPUUtilization%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Namespace%3A%20AWS%2FEC2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Period%3A%20%27300%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Statistic%3A%20Average%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Threshold%3A%20%2790%27%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3ACloudWatch%3A%3AAlarm%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceCloudWatchCPUAlarmLow%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AlarmActions%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceAutoscaleDownPolicy%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentserviceSNSTopic%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AlarmDescription%3A%20SNS%20Notification%20and%20scale%20down%20if%20CPU%20Util%20is%20less%20than%2070%25%20for%2010%20mins%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ComparisonOperator%3A%20LessThanThreshold%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Dimensions%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Name%3A%20AutoScalingGroupName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Value%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceASG%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20EvaluationPeriods%3A%20%272%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20MetricName%3A%20CPUUtilization%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Namespace%3A%20AWS%2FEC2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Period%3A%20%27300%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Statistic%3A%20Average%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Threshold%3A%20%2770%27%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3ACloudWatch%3A%3AAlarm%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceELB%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ConnectionDrainingPolicy%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Enabled%3A%20%27true%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Timeout%3A%20%2760%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20CrossZone%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20HealthCheck%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HealthyThreshold%3A%20%273%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Interval%3A%20%2715%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Target%3A%20%27HTTP%3A80%2Findex.html%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Timeout%3A%20%275%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UnhealthyThreshold%3A%20%273%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Listeners%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20InstancePort%3A%20%2780%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceProtocol%3A%20HTTP%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LoadBalancerPort%3A%20%2780%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Protocol%3A%20HTTP%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20LoadBalancerName%3A%20AgentServiceELB%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Scheme%3A%20internet-facing%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SecurityGroups%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Subnets%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20PublicSubnets%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Tags%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Key%3A%20Network%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Value%3A%20public%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AElasticLoadBalancing%3A%3ALoadBalancer%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceLaunchConfig%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AssociatePublicIpAddress%3A%20%27true%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20IamInstanceProfile%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20InstanceProfile%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ImageId%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20WindowsAMIID%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceType%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20InstanceType%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20KeyName%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20KeyName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SecurityGroups%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Ref%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20UserData%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Fn%3A%3ABase64%27%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Fn%3A%3AJoin%27%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20-%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20echo%20hello%20world%20%3E%20c%3A%5C%5Cinetpub%5C%5Cwwwroot%5C%5Cindex.html%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hostname%20%3E%3E%20c%3A%5C%5Cinetpub%5C%5Cwwwroot%5C%5Cindex.html%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%22if%20not%20exist%20%5C%5C%22c%3A%5C%5Ctemp%5C%5C%22%20mkdir%20c%3A%5C%5Ctemp%5C%5Cn%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20powershell.exe%20-Command%20Read-S3Object%20-BucketName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aws-codedeploy-us-east-1%2Flatest%20-Key%20codedeploy-agent.msi%20-File%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%5C%5Ctemp%5C%5Ccodedeploy-agent.msi%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%5C%5Ctemp%5C%5Ccodedeploy-agent.msi%20%2Fquiet%20%2Fl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%5C%5Ctemp%5C%5Chost-agent-install-log.txt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20powershell.exe%20-Command%20Get-Service%20-Name%20codedeployagent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AAutoScaling%3A%3ALaunchConfiguration%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceSNSTopic%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3ASNS%3A%3ATopic%27%0A%20%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupDescription%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceAccessHTTPS%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CidrIp%3A%200.0.0.0%2F0%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FromPort%3A%20%27443%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupId%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IpProtocol%3A%20tcp%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ToPort%3A%20%27443%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3ASecurityGroupIngress%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceAccessPSremote%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CidrIp%3A%20198.18.0.0%2F24%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FromPort%3A%20%275985%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupId%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IpProtocol%3A%20tcp%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ToPort%3A%20%275985%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3ASecurityGroupIngress%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceAccessRDP%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CidrIp%3A%200.0.0.0%2F0%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FromPort%3A%20%273389%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupId%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IpProtocol%3A%20tcp%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ToPort%3A%20%273389%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3ASecurityGroupIngress%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20InstanceAccessSMB%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CidrIp%3A%20198.18.0.0%2F24%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FromPort%3A%20%27445%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupId%3A%20AgentServiceSecurityGroup%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IpProtocol%3A%20tcp%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ToPort%3A%20%27445%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3ASecurityGroupIngress%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20VpcId%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ref%3A%20VPCID%0A%20%20%20%20Type%3A%20%27AWS%3A%3AEC2%3A%3ASecurityGroup%27&type=json) and [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/) both complain when you use your YAML as input. After changing the  line these YAML parsers indicate as problematic:

```
- "if not exist \\"c:\\temp\\" mkdir c:\\temp\\n"
```

which is a quoted scalar `"if not exist \\"c:\\temp\\"` followed by more `mkdir ...` into:

```
- "if not exist \"c:\\temp\" mkdir c:\\temp\n"
```

in which the quotes are escaped, or to the better readable:

```
- |
  if not exist "c:\temp" mkdir c:\temp
```

The [Code Beautify YAML Validator](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator) complain that your YAML has problems, but as usual cannot deal with the corrected YAML either, so don't use that.